# Bootstrap carousel arrow shadows taking the whole right side

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I can't figure out why there are shadows on the right side of my page.

Can somebody can tell me what is wrong with my code and how to make the shadows disappear? The shadows are the same as those of the carousel "prev" and "next" arrows.

Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
<title>Page Title</title>


<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media  queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js">         </script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'></script>
</head>






<body>
  <!--Navbar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"  id="my-navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Wiredwiki</a>
    </div> <!--Navbar Header-->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
      <a href="" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn navbar-right">Download now</a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#feedback">Feedback</a>
          <li><a href="#Gallery">Gallery</a>
          <li><a href="#Features">Features</a>
          <li><a href="#FAQ">FAQ</a>
          <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
        </ul>
    </div> 
  </div><!-- End container-->
</nav><!--End navbar-->

<!--Jumbotron-->

<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container text-center">
       <h1>Wiredwiki App</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
             sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
             aliqua. </p>
          <div class="btn-group">
              <a href="" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">Download App</a>
              <a href="" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Visit Store</a>
              <a href="" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">Spread the word</a>
          </div>
    </div> <!--End container-->
</div><!--End Jumbotron-->

<div class="container" >
    <section>
      <div class="page-header" id="feedback">
          <h2>Feedback. <small>Check out the awsome feedback</small></h2>
      </div>

      <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <blockquote>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
             sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
             aliqua.</p>
            <footer>John Doe</footer>
          </blockquote>
        </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <blockquote>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
               sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
               aliqua.</p>
              <footer>John Doe</footer>
            </blockquote>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <blockquote>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
               sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
               aliqua.</p>
              <footer>John Doe</footer>
            </blockquote>
          </div>

      </div><!-- End row -->
    </section>
</div><!--End container-->

 <!-- Call to action -->
    <section>
    <div class="well">
     <div class="container text-center">
      <h3> Subscribe for more free stuff</h3>
      <p>Enter your name and email</p>

      <form action="" class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="subscription">Subscribe</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subscription" placeholder="Your name">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Email">Email address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter your Email">
      </div>
      <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-default">Subscribe</button>
      <hr>
    </form>
   </div> <!--End container-->
   </div> <!--end well-->
  </section> <!--End call to action-->

<!-- Gallery -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
  <section>
  <div class="container page-header" id="Gallery">
    <h2>Gallery.<small> Check out the awsome gallery </small></h2>
  </div>

  <!-- Carousel -->
  <div class="carousel slide" id="screenshot-carousel" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://bit.ly/1JkGO3n">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Awsome caption</h3>
            <p>Awsome caption for you to see</p>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://bit.ly/1Ld5r88">
         <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Awsome caption</h3>
            <p>Awsome caption for you to see</p>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://bit.ly/1HRXka8">
         <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Awsome caption</h3>
            <p>Awsome caption for you to see</p>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://bit.ly/1RBVsNz">
         <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Awsome caption</h3>
            <p>Awsome caption for you to see</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- End Carousel inner -->

      <!--arrow controls-->
      <a href="#screenshot-carousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"
      </a>

      <a href="#screenshot-carousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"
      </a>
      <!-- End arrow controls-->

  </div> <!-- End Carousel -->



 </section>
  </div>
  </div>
 <!-- End Gallery -->












 <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're `nav` `li` are not closed with `</li>` and your carousel controls where also not closed: `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"` missing `> </span>`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Wiredwiki</a> 
    </div>
    <!--Navbar Header-->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse"> <a href="" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn navbar-right">Download now</a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#feedback">Feedback</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Gallery">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Features">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#FAQ">FAQ</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End container-->
</nav>
<!--End navbar-->
<!--Jumbotron-->
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <h1>Wiredwiki App</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <div class="btn-group"> <a href="" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">Download App</a>  <a href="" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Visit Store</a>  <a href="" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">Spread the word</a> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--End container-->
</div>
<!--End Jumbotron-->
<div class="container">
  <section>
    <div class="page-header" id="feedback">
      <h2>Feedback. <small>Check out the awsome feedback</small></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <blockquote>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <footer>John Doe</footer>
        </blockquote>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <blockquote>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <footer>John Doe</footer>
        </blockquote>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <blockquote>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <footer>John Doe</footer>
        </blockquote>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End row -->
  </section>
</div>
<!--End container-->
<!-- Call to action -->
<section>
  <div class="well">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <h3> Subscribe for more free stuff</h3>
      <p>Enter your name and email</p>
      <form action="" class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="subscription">Subscribe</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subscription" placeholder="Your name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Email">Email address</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter your Email">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Subscribe</button>
        <hr>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!--End container-->
  </div>
  <!--end well-->
</section>
<!--End call to action-->
<!-- Gallery -->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <section>
      <div class="container page-header" id="Gallery">
        <h2>Gallery.<small> Check out the awsome gallery </small></h2>
      </div>
      <!-- Carousel -->
      <div class="carousel slide" id="screenshot-carousel" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x550/f00/fff">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Awsome caption</h3>
              <p>Awsome caption for you to see</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x550/f00/fff">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Awsome caption</h3>
              <p>Awsome caption for you to see</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x550/f00/fff">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Awsome caption</h3>
              <p>Awsome caption for you to see</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x550/f00/fff">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Awsome caption</h3>
              <p>Awsome caption for you to see</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Carousel inner -->
        <!--arrow controls-->
        <a href="#screenshot-carousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
         <a href="#screenshot-carousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a> 
        
        <!-- End arrow controls--> 
      </div>
      <!-- End Carousel --> 
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Gallery -->
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Helped me out a bunch